# Nums and mods using python, easy question

Tags: python, python-3.x, logic

Given a non-negative number "num", return True if num is within 2 of a multiple of 10. Note: (a % b) is the remainder of dividing a by b, so (7 % 5) is 2.

Basically know how to code for this type of stuff and this is considered easy, but I just cant understand the question. Please help, you kind stranger!

Answer (score 0):

You want num be to within 2 of 10, 20, 30... so num = 8, 9, 10, 11, 12... 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, and so on... should all return True.

Using properties of mod 10, this means is that (num % 10) ≤ 2 or (num %10) ≥ 8 since (num % 10) is non-negative and also cannot exceed 10.

```
def my_func(num):
    if (num % 10 <= 2) or (num % 10 >= 8): 
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Sample output:

```
>>> my_func(18)
    True
>>> my_func(22)
    True
>>> my_func(23)
    False
```

Answer (score 0):

**welcome** to the stackoverflow.

It means that we have to return true if number modulus 10 is within the range of 2

```
 k=int(input())
 p=k%10
 if(10-p)<=2 or (10-(10-p))<=2):
     return True
 else:
     return False
```

In if condition two possible outcomes is considered, p would be either in [8,10] or [10,12].
Hope it helps